# Is it a very serious bug in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

On client side I asked for 950$. Got a token.
On server side I sent to Stripe the token, but charged an amount of 50,0000 $

And it WAS OK !!!

Client side:

```
    <StripeCheckout
      name={props.event.name}
      description={ new Date(props.event.date).toDateString() + ' ' + placeText}
      amount={props.event.price * 100}
      token={token => props.onPay(token, props.event._id)}
      stripeKey={'pk_test_XXXXX......'}
    >
```

Server side:

```
module.exports = app => {
  app.post('/api/stripe', async (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body);
    const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
      amount: 5000000,
       currency: 'usd',
       description: '$5 for 5 credits',
       source: req.body.token.id
   });

    // req.user.credits += 5;
    // const user = await req.user.save();

    // res.send(user);
  });
};
```

Report from Stripe https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1FEgvCHkOtkcBWyN/ch_1FHxt4HkOtkcBWyNCyylE9qA/rcpt_FnZ1rB8Nthi7Ny2zD4XS32OAcAGBsd7

Log from server side:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --inspect-brk=29051 server.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:29051/3335c9cc-dc3d-47cd-a1e0-dfcb87c40a1b
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Listening on port 8080...

charge
Object {id: "ch_1FHxt4HkOtkcBWyNCyylE9qA", object: "charge", amount: 5000000, amount_refunded: 0, application: null, …}
[[StableObjectId]]: 4
amount: 5000000
amount_refunded: 0
application: null
application_fee: null
application_fee_amount: null
balance_transaction: "txn_1FHxt4HkOtkcBWyNd0aqWzqH"
billing_details: Object {address: Object, email: null, name: "dfsdf@dsfs.com", …}
captured: true
created: 1568316206
currency: "usd"
customer: null
description: "$5 for 5 credits"
destination: null
dispute: null
failure_code: null
failure_message: null
fraud_details: Object {}
id: "ch_1FHxt4HkOtkcBWyNCyylE9qA"
invoice: null
lastResponse: IncomingMessage {_readableState: ReadableState, readable: false, _events: Object, …}
livemode: false
metadata: Object {}
object: "charge"
on_behalf_of: null
order: null
outcome: Object {network_status: "approved_by_network", reason: null, risk_level: "normal", …}
paid: true
payment_intent: null
payment_method: "card_1FHxstHkOtkcBWyNEHkn9GxE"
payment_method_details: Object {card: Object, type: "card"}
receipt_email: null
receipt_number: null
receipt_url: "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1FEgvCHkOtkcBWyN/ch_1FHxt4HkOtkcBWyNCyylE9qA/rcpt_FnZ1rB8Nthi7Ny2zD4XS32OAcAGBsd7"
refunded: false
refunds: Object {object: "list", data: Array(0), has_more: false, …}
review: null
shipping: null
source: Object {id: "card_1FHxstHkOtkcBWyNEHkn9GxE", object: "card", address_city: null, …}
source_transfer: null
statement_descriptor: null
statement_descriptor_suffix: null
status: "succeeded"
transfer_data: null
transfer_group: null
__proto__: Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , …}
```

Comment: What you're doing there is charging the card for `amount: 5000000` after telling the cardholder you planned to charge for a lower amount. Not a bug in Stripe, but rather a way to create payments that will likely be disputed by the cardholder.

Comment: Really?, Is that so? A hacker creates a malicious web site and somehow lures a naive user to pay 1$, but charges 1000$ or more sophisticated scenario asks for 6$ , but charges 10$ (a user may not pay attention or malicious site owner can say that it is a shipping cost or whatever). I am not so good in internet scamps and frauds but I am sure there are plenty of options. Not a bug at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount you're asking client-side is just for UI purposes in Legacy Checkout and it does not control how much you would charge server-side when creating the Charge via the API.

This is similar to creating your own payment form via Elements, displaying the amount you want to charge (which Stripe does not control) and then charging a different amount server-side.

You can also save the card on a Customer and charge it again in the future for example for extra services for the customer or incidentals.

This is not a security issue really. When you charge an amount different from what you told your customers, you're opening yourself to disputes as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/disputes).